# I will never know the decoding and encoding system of python2.7

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Sorry for asking question like a fool, but maybe someone could help me get out of the decode/encode hell of python2.7

I have a string as below, I'm not sure but I think it's encoded as UTF-8 because I wrote`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the head of the py file

```
s = "今日もしないとね"
```

and as my point of view, if it's a string, part of it could be printed out by using [] like this:

```
print s[1]
```

Then I got a error in my sublime:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
```

I tried in terminal I got a

```
?
```

Okay, maybe a part of a utf-8 string would become not an utf-8 string, so I tried:

```
print s[1].encode("utf-8")
```

then I got this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I was totally confused. Does it mean that a part of a string is a ascii like`\xbb`?

Could anybody tell me what are the encoding of the following stuff?

```
a = "今日もしないとね"
b = u"今日もしないとね"
c = "python2.7 fxxked me"
d = u"python2.7 fxxked me"
e = "今"
f = "z"
aa = a[0]
bb = b[0]
cc = c[0]
dd = d[0]
```

and How to get `"今日"` from `"今日,もしないとね"`?

Thank you!

Comment: I suggest you start with e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks, I think I should read it first

Comment: Another suggested reading: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/07/Getting-unicode-right-in-Python

Comment: Make sure that your code editor is actually set to save files in UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is correctly encoded in UTF-8 but your operating system doesn't (directly) support Unicode on output.

The right way to specify a Unicode string literal in Python 2 is using the "u" prefix. Only in this case the Unicode string is actually stored there.

By the way, you can see what Python actually *thinks* about your variable content using the `repr` function:

```
>>> print a
'\xe4\xbb\x8a\xe6\x97\xa5\xe3\x82\x82\xe3\x81\x97\xe3\x81\xaa\xe3\x81\x84\xe3\x81\xa8\xe3\x81\xad'
>>> print b
u'\u4eca\u65e5\u3082\u3057\u306a\u3044\u3068\u306d'
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments suggest - unicode isn't as easy to discover-learn as many other parts of Python

The following code sample will print "今日"

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
b = u"今日もしないとね"
print b[:2]
```

however - the coding line only tells *Python* how to interpret those bytes in the file. Many editors won't look for the coding line and you'll need to make sure that they are in fact also using utf-8 when working out how to display those bytes to you.

When Python gets to the print statement, it will take the unicode object `b` and *encode* it using `sys.stdout.encoding`. Now this better also match your terminal/console settings, or you will get some garbage printed instead.